# Elastic cloud vs elastic search on local server

Tags: elasticsearch

> Does the  Elastic cloud and elastic search setup on local machine consumes the same speed for data gathering ?

Answer (score 2):

Well it depends on (your local setup).

1. How many machines/nodes
2. How much CPU and memory per node. And one of most important is if nodes has SSD
3. It depends on network.

In [ElasticCloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud/as-a-service/pricing) you can choose amount of memory and storage, but not amount of nodes (Nodes depends on amount of memory because its better to have one node with 32 gigs of memory than 3 nodes with 10 gb for instance.) Also important that EsCloud setup is using SSD.

So again all of that depends while local setup will give you more flexibility and control, but cloud could simplify your life.

One more option would be to go with AWS or Azure because you will be able to add remove nodes on demands so it would be a bit easier to experiment and see what setup is better for you.

To Sum up: if we are talking that you have same setup locally and same setup in cloud there will be no difference in terms of performance but, only one thing would be different its latency.

Comment: Also is that good if create separate index for each mysql table ?

Comment: @ZohaibAhmad you must understand that ES is document storage and it does not support joins. So in many cases you cant just store same objects from db to ES you need to add extra info if required(For instance user may need to have address with it). But yes its good practice to store one type of data in 1 index. If you need later you can search across multiple indexes at once

Comment: yep i know ES does not support joins . we can relate indexes with each other or we can do via parent child relationships.

Comment: I have 3 or four table which i wanna put in to ES from mysql for search would that be feasible ?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat how easy would it be to migrate from cloud to local?